# Macbook при загрузке не видит встроенный диск

Tags: macbook

Проблема. После удаления всех разделов на диске и создания новых, при загрузке не видит вообще ни одного диска. Как корректно подмонтировать и указать с какого диска грузится. Во вкладке загрузочные тома нет ни одного диска. Возможно нужно прописать мбр? При загрузке появляется мигающий вопрос с папкой. Пытаюсь через bless    прописать загрузочный том эффекта нет.

Comment: возможно, Вы создали "неподходящие" типы разделов.

Comment: раздел один в hfs